# possible to $.post and get a file download dialog back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm using jquery's $.post and was wondering if I can use this to get a FileResult back? Not having any success yet? The content is coming back in the callback but not as a file download?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

Instead, you can submit a regular `<form>` using Javascript that responds with `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using pure Ajax. You would have to redirect the browser to the file resource somehow. (See my last bullet point for a possible exception from this rule.)

What you could do:

- Get a file URL back and redirect to it in your `success` callback: `location.href='...'`
- Get a file URL back and set it as the `src` of a newly created `iframe` (would prevent current page from closing / freezing) `$("#iframe").attr("src", "....");`
- Maybe - I haven't used it myself yet but it looks like it can do this - receive the data and make it a local file download using [Doug Neiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152083/doug-neiner)'s [Downloadify](http://downloadify.info/)