# Is it possible and clean to respond to a POST with a download?

Tags: ajax, http, download

I'm implementing a service that converts a file on the server, but I don't want to store anything, just return the converted file. Is it possible/feasible to respond to a POST with a file download? I'm using ajax, so I don't want to navigate away from the page.

I simply tried setting the content type to application/octet-stream, which works, but gives an unfortunate warning in Chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream

I would like to have the flexibility to return either the download, or an error report on the response. What would be a smart solution for this, or can this only be done cleanly via a redirect?

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789623/possible-to-post-and-get-a-file-download-dialog-back), which is closely related, I have tried to respond with a Content-Disposition=attachment, instead of just the Content-Type=application/octet-stream. This takes care of the warning, but it still leaves the question of wether responding with a download is *appropriate* for a POST.